# How to add a 2-element list to a python dictionary as a key/value pair?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add the content of a 2-element list to a python dictionary (python3). The first element is the key, the second element is the value.

I followed [this documentation](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/51791644.html) but maybe I misunderstood the content.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
mydict = {"test": "1"}
key_value_pair = ["test2", "42"]
mydict.update(key_value_pair)
```

with the expected result to have a dict with two entries:

```
{
    "test": "1",
    "test2" : "42"
}
```

but instead I get an error `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required`.

Sure I can do it as follows:

```
mydict[key_value_pair[0]] = key_value_pair[1]
```

but the idea is to split a string and use the two elements directly as key/value pair:

```
mystring = "test2=42"
mydict.update(mystring.split("="))
```

instead of

```
mystring = "test4=42"
splitted_string = mystring.split("=")
mydict[splitted_string[0]] = splitted_string[1]
```

I hope you see the point...

Comment: ```mydict.update((["test2", "42"],))```.

Comment: Notice the presence of ```,```.

Comment: Yes I saw the `,` was the ""key""...   Perfect, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> but the idea is to split a string and use the two elements directly as key/value pair:

If you want to split the string and use the two elements *directly* as key/value pair, then I think this is the simplest way to go:

```
mydict = {"test": "1"}
mydict.update(["test2=42".split("=")]) # this statement
print(mydict)
```

This prints as expected:

`{'test': '1', 'test2': '42'}`

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys. Return None.
> `update()` accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two). If keyword arguments are specified, the dictionary is then updated with those key/value pairs: `d.update(red=1, blue=2)`.

So when you provide an `iterable`, it expects each element of the iterable to be a key-value pair.

That's why this works:

```
kvp = ["newkey", "newval"]
mydict.update([kvp])
```

Each element of the input iterable is a 2-element list.

When you do just

```
mydict.update(kvp)
```

`update()` tries to ensure that each element of `kvp` is a 2-element iterable. Since strings are iterable, you get the error that the length of the element is invalid.

---

Side note: if `kvp` contained integers, or something that isn't iterable:

```
kvp2 = [0, 42]
mydict.update(kvp2)
```

You'd get this error

> TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

---

So, to update the dict with the result of a `split()` operation, you simply need to wrap that list in another iterable (a list in the following example).

```
mystring = "test2=42"
mydict.update([mystring.split("=")])
```

Now if you wanted that iterable to be a tuple, there's a small gotcha. Just wrapping `mystring.split()` in parentheses like so: `(mystring.split("="))` won't create the tuple. Instead, you need to add the comma `(mystring.split("="), )` to get it to create a tuple.

```
t1 = (mystring.split("="))
print(type(t1))
# Output: list
t2 = (mystring.split("="), )
print(type(t2))
# Output: tuple

mydict.update((mystring.split("="), ))
```

If you had a list of `N` strings that alternated between keys and values, it'd be fairly easy to reshape it into a `N/2 x 2` list of key-value pairs:

```
mydict = {"test": "1"}

all_kvp = ["key1", "val1", "key2", "val2", "key3", "val3"]
kvp = [(k, v) for k, v in zip(all_kvp[::2], all_kvp[1::2])] # creates a list-of-tuples, but a list-of-lists would also work.

mydict.update(kvp)
# mydict: {'test': '1', 'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

> `update()` accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two).

In case of your code there was an exception because `"test2"` is an iterable but of length 5 rather than 2.

You could e.g. wrap your list of 2 into another list to make it work:

```py
>>> mydict = {"test": "1"}
... key_value_pair = ["test2", "42"]
... mydict.update([key_value_pair])
>>> mydict
{'test': '1', 'test2': '42'}
```